# Rank the managers based on how many employees they have

Tags: oracle, greatest-n-per-group

[Update]

Thanks for all the comments!
Appreciated!

I solved this by the code below, after referring to all of your posts.
I did not put into account of hierarchy but I will for the later works.
Thank you!

```
SELECT m.first_name
  , m.last_name
  , RANK() over (partition by (select COUNT(e.employee_id) 
                               from DB1_employee e) 
                 ORDER BY e.employee_id DESC) AS RANK from DB2_manager m LEFT JOIN RITDB_employee e ON m.employee_id=e.manager
```

I am having difficulty to troubleshoot my code to rank the managers
based on the number of employees they have. The error is "missing right parenthesis". Any helps would be highly appreciated. Thanks!

```
SELECT m.first_name
      , m.last_name
      , RANK() over (partition by (select COUNT(e.employee_id) 
                                   from DB1_employee e) AS NUM_EMP 
                     ORDER BY NUM_EMP DESC) AS RANK 
from DB2_manager m
     , DB1_employee e 
group by m.first_name, m.last_name 
ORDER BY RANK
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all

- Your query is doing a cross join, and then grouping by manager name. There can be an issue if two managers have the same name. Better to use PK and FK.
- Don't use old join syntax
- `NUM_EMP`. has no reference in your query and still used in the `ORDER BY`.

I am considering that `DB1_employee` table must have some column referring to its manager(let's say, `MANAGER_FK` ). So writing the query accordingly as following:

```
SELECT
    M.FIRST_NAME,
    M.LAST_NAME,
    RANK() OVER(
        ORDER BY
            E.EMPLOYEE_CNT DESC
    ) AS RNK
FROM
    DB2_MANAGER M
    JOIN (
        SELECT
            MANAGER_FK,
            COUNT(1) AS EMPLOYEE_CNT
        FROM
            DB1_EMPLOYEE
        GROUP BY
            MANAGER_FK
    ) E ON ( M.MANAGER_ID = E.MANAGER_FK )
ORDER BY
    RNK;
```

Cheers!!

Answer (score 2):

An example based on Scott's schema (as I don't have your tables nor data), so that it is easier to see what should be returned.

```
SQL> select mgr, empno, ename, job from emp order by mgr;

       MGR      EMPNO ENAME      JOB
---------- ---------- ---------- ---------
      7566       7902 FORD       ANALYST        --> MGR 7566 (Jones)  has 2 employees
      7566       7788 SCOTT      ANALYST
      7698       7900 JAMES      CLERK          -->     7698 (Blake)  has 5 employees
      7698       7499 ALLEN      SALESMAN
      7698       7521 WARD       SALESMAN
      7698       7844 TURNER     SALESMAN
      7698       7654 MARTIN     SALESMAN
      7782       7934 MILLER     CLERK          -->     7782 (Clark)  has 1 employee
      7788       7876 ADAMS      CLERK          -->     7788 (Scott)  has 1 employee
      7839       7698 BLAKE      MANAGER        -->     7839 (King)   has 3 employees
      7839       7566 JONES      MANAGER
      7839       7782 CLARK      MANAGER
      7902       7369 SMITH      CLERK          -->     7902 (Ford)   has 1 employee 
                 7839 KING       PRESIDENT

14 rows selected.

SQL>
```

So:

```
SQL> select m.ename mgrname,
  2         count(*) cnt,
  3         dense_rank() over (order by count(*) desc) rnk
  4  from emp e join emp m on e.mgr = m.empno
  5  where e.mgr is not null
  6  group by e.mgr, m.ename
  7  order by rnk;

MGRNAME           CNT        RNK
---------- ---------- ----------
BLAKE               5          1
KING                3          2
JONES               2          3
SCOTT               1          4
FORD                1          4
CLARK               1          4

6 rows selected.

SQL>
```

---

### However:

That's not correct. Why? Because of hierarchy. Not all managers share the same level. Have a look: King is the **president**; he is the big boss and manages them all; how can he be ranked as #2? The same goes for the rest of them.

```
SQL> select lpad(' ', 2 * level - 2) || e.empno ||' '|| e.ename val
  2  from emp e
  3  connect by prior e.empno = e.mgr
  4  start with e.mgr is null;

VAL
--------------------------------------------------------------------
7839 KING
  7566 JONES               --> Jones has 4 employees!!! (Scott, Adams, Ford and Smith)
    7788 SCOTT                 --> Scott has 1 employee (that's Adams)
      7876 ADAMS
    7902 FORD                  --> Ford  has 1 employee (that's Smith)
      7369 SMITH
  7698 BLAKE
    7499 ALLEN
    7521 WARD
    7654 MARTIN
    7844 TURNER
    7900 JAMES
  7782 CLARK
    7934 MILLER

14 rows selected.

SQL>
```

Therefore, we need another approach. Begin with a simple query which, basically, returns "root" for each of them:

```
SQL> select connect_by_root(ename) manager
  2  from emp
  3  connect by prior empno = mgr;

MANAGER
----------
SCOTT
SCOTT
FORD
FORD
ALLEN
JAMES

<snip>

KING
KING

39 rows selected.

SQL>
```

It is further used as a source for

```
SQL> select x.mgrname,
  2         count(*) - 1 cnt
  3  from (select connect_by_root(e.ename) mgrname
  4        from emp e
  5        connect by prior e.empno = e.mgr
  6       ) x
  7  group by x.mgrname;

MGRNAME           CNT
---------- ----------
ALLEN               0
JONES               4
FORD                1
MILLER              0
CLARK               1
WARD                0
SMITH               0
SCOTT               1
TURNER              0
MARTIN              0
ADAMS               0
JAMES               0
BLAKE               5
KING               13

14 rows selected.

SQL>
```

**Finally**, remove those that don't have any employees and rank them; the result is quite different than the first (the most obvious, but probably wrong) approach:

```
SQL> select r.mgrname,
  2         r.cnt,
  3         dense_rank() over (order by cnt desc) rnk
  4  from (select x.mgrname,
  5               count(*) - 1 cnt
  6        from (select connect_by_root(e.ename) mgrname
  7              from emp e
  8              connect by prior e.empno = e.mgr
  9             ) x
 10        group by x.mgrname
 11       ) r
 12  where r.cnt > 0
 13  order by rnk;

MGRNAME           CNT        RNK
---------- ---------- ----------
KING               13          1
BLAKE               5          2
JONES               4          3
SCOTT               1          4
FORD                1          4
CLARK               1          4

6 rows selected.

SQL>
```

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
SELECT m.first_name
  , m.last_name
  , RANK() over (partition by (select COUNT(e.employee_id) 
                               from DB1_employee e) 
                 ORDER BY NUM_EMP DESC) AS RANK 
from DB2_manager m
     , DB1_employee e 
group by m.first_name, m.last_name 
ORDER BY RANK
;
```